# I want to generate four log files for warning, debug, error, and info. I want to control which file should be print at run time

Tags: go

```
package Loggers

import (
    "io"
    "os"
    "log"
)

var logCloser io.Closer
func MyLogger() {
    logFile, err := os.OpenFile("C:/Git/goclassec/src/gclassec/Logs/log.txt", os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND|os.O_RDWR, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    logCloser = logFile
    log.SetOutput(logFile)
}
func CloseMyLogger() {
    logCloser.Close()
}
```

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: //We can System Log also if required to achieve this target.

Comment: What you want to do is clear but what is your concern here ?

Comment: I am trying to generate Log for Error (log.error), Debug(log.debug), warning(log.warn) and info(log.info) but not able to achieve. This code is only generating log all in one file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `log.New` to create different loggers and wrap it inside your MyLogger

This is the New format

```
 New(out io.Writer, prefix string, flag int)
```

Here is a sample implementation

**Code**

```
package loggers

import (
    "log"
    "os"
)

//MyLogger custom logger
type MyLogger struct {
    ErrorL *log.Logger
    InfoL  *log.Logger
    DebugL *log.Logger
}

//New returns logger
//TODO : deal with error
func New() *MyLogger {
    ml := new(MyLogger)
    if logFile, err := os.OpenFile("C:/Git/goclassec/src/gclassec/Logs/log_error.txt", os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND|os.O_RDWR, 0666); err == nil {
        ml.ErrorL = log.New(logFile, "ERROR", log.LUTC)
    }
    if logFile, err := os.OpenFile("C:/Git/goclassec/src/gclassec/Logs/log_info.txt", os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND|os.O_RDWR, 0666); err == nil {
        ml.InfoL = log.New(logFile, "INFO", log.LUTC)
    }
    if logFile, err := os.OpenFile("C:/Git/goclassec/src/gclassec/Logs/log_debug.txt", os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND|os.O_RDWR, 0666); err == nil {
        ml.DebugL = log.New(logFile, "DEBUG", log.LUTC)
    }
    return ml
}

func (ml MyLogger) Error(data ...interface{}) {
    ml.ErrorL.Println(data...)
}

func (ml MyLogger) Info(data ...interface{}) {
    ml.InfoL.Println(data...)
}

func (ml MyLogger) Debug(data ...interface{}) {
    ml.DebugL.Println(data...)
}
```

**Usage**

```
logger := loggers.New()
logger.Error("Error occured",err)
logger.Info("Doing","something","again","blah")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, can u pls tell me what we are passing in the place of data ...interface{} and data...

Comment: @AnkurTiwari you can pass anything. Just like how you use fmt.Println . Please accept the answer